# How call function with parameters

Tags: swift

How to call function like this ?

```
func addWatermark(inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler:@escaping (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?)-> Void) {

    }
```

This is my code

```
       // Call function 
  addWatermark(inputURL: videoURL! as URL, outputURL: videoURL! as URL, handler: @escaping ()-> Void)
```

> Cannot convert value of type '(() -> Void).Type' to expected argument
>   type '(AVAssetExportSession?) -> Void'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't use `NSURL` in Swift 3+. Use native `URL`, this avoids the ugly bridge casts.

The syntax to call the function is supposed to look like

```
addWatermark(inputURL: videoURL!, outputURL: videoURL) { exportSession in

}
```

`exportSession` is the passed `AVAssetExportSession?` parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try a trailing closure like this:

```
addWatermark(inputURL: videoURL! as URL, outputURL: videoURL! as URL) { exportSession in 

}
```

Or the more verbose option:

```
addWatermark(inputURL: videoURL, outputURL: videoURL, handler: { exportSession in

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Call you're function like this:

```
func addWatermark(inputURL: videoURL! as URL, outputURL: videoURL! as URL) { exportSession in

}
```